# Code transformation from Scala to Pyspark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am very new to Scala and Pyspark, I have to transform this piece of code which is written in Scala to Pyspark. can someone help me to understand the syntax in Scala in order to be able to transform it?

```
val df= spark.read.parquet(s"$basePath/dod_m/")
.select(df2.map(x => col(x._1).as(x._2)).toList :_*)
```

Comment: Where is df2 defined?

Comment: Df2 is defined in upper part of code and it is pyspark data frame

Comment: But I just didnt put it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, `df2` is a simple scala collection here.

If it were a dataframe, `df2.map(x => col(x._1).as(x._2))` would yield `error: value _1 is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row`. Indeed, the `map` function on a dataframe allows you to work on a `Row` object, not a tuple.

If it were a dataset of `(String, String)` for instance, `df2.map(x => col(x._1).as(x._2))` would yield: `error: Unable to find encoder for type org.apache.spark.sql.Column.`. If you define such an encoder, you would obtain `error: value toList is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Column]` which is rather clear.

RDDs do not possess the `toList` method either.

So let's consider `df2` to be a scala collection of `(String, String)`. `df2.map(x => col(x._1).as(x._2)).toList` is about renaming columns. Former names are the first element of the tuple, new names the second element.

An example in scala:

```scala
val df2 = Seq(("a", "b"), ("c", "d"))
val df = Seq((1, 2), (4, 5)).toDF("a", "c")

// running this in a shell, we see that it is about renaming columns
df2.map(x => col(x._1).as(x._2)).toList
//res2: List[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = List(a AS b, c AS d)
```

Let's try:

```scala
df.show
+---+---+
|  a|  c|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  4|  5|
+---+---+


df.select(df2.map(x => col(x._1).as(x._2)).toList :_*).show
+---+---+
|  b|  d|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  4|  5|
+---+---+
```

in python:

```py
df2 = [("a", "b"), ("c", "d")]
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2), (4, 5)], ['a', 'c'])
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.select([f.col(x[0]).alias(x[1]) for x in df2]).show()
+---+---+
|  b|  d|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  4|  5|
+---+---+
```